# vim - how to match linked sequences in syntax file

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want to create a syntax file in vim for a custom file type I have. Part of the syntax is this line

```
entry: 1,02:15:00,03:15:00,56,Some String
```

I would like to match every part separately to assign different colors. `entry` should be a part, `1` should be a part, `02:15:00` should be a part, `03:15:00` should be a different part, `56` yet another part, `Some String` a different part, and all `,`s as a part. Each of these should be named differently so I can color them with different colors as needed.

I was able to match them with `contains`, but similar values (first time and second time) get the same name. I also tried using `nextgroup` to chain them one after another, but this left me with `,` having many names I need to color separately (and there are many commas in the original file not like the simple example I shown here).

Is there a way to do such syntax highlighting in a proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link all comma names to one with

```
" Adjust the below to make commas have another color.
" It is common that instead of defining colors directly you link 
" new highlighting groups to some standard one.
hi def link MySyntaxComma Delimiter

hi def link MySyntaxCommaAfterNumber       MySyntaxComma
hi def link MySyntaxCommaAfterFirstTime    MySyntaxComma
hi def link MySyntaxCommaAfterSecondTime   MySyntaxComma
hi def link MySyntaxCommaAfterSecondNumber MySyntaxComma
```

You can also use a loop with `:execute` to hide the repeating rules:

```
syntax match MySyntaxEntryStart /^entry:\s*/ nextgroup=MySyntaxNumber1
let s:rules=[['Number1', '\d\+'], ['Time1', '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'], ['Time2', '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d'], ['Number2', '\d\+'], ['String', '.*']]
while !empty(s:rules)
    let [s:name, s:reg]=remove(s:rules, 0)
    let s:cmd='syntax match MySyntax'.s:name.' /'.s:reg.'/ contained'
    if !empty(s:rules)
        let s:cmd.=' nextgroup=MySyntaxCommaAfter'.s:name
        execute 'syntax match MySyntaxCommaAfter'.s:name.' /,/ contained nextgroup=MySyntax'.s:rules[0][0]
        execute 'hi def link MySyntaxCommaAfter'.s:name.' MySyntaxComma'
    endif
    execute s:cmd
endwhile
unlet s:rules s:cmd s:name s:reg
```

Comment: If you think about it, it is the same as coloring each of them, as I still need to link them. what you suggested is a good practice. The problem originally is that there are many commas, so I thought maybe there is a command such as `separator` or `inbetween` just like there is `start` and `end`. I'll mark your answer since I guess this the best it can get.

Comment: @ccit You can’t have normal nextgroup chain with one separator matching rule. The best you can do is combining all the bloat into one smaller cycle with :execute (will update the answer with the example).

Comment: You are great. The new suggestion is exactly what I need. I never thought to use programming (looping and such) to solve it. Clever solution, therefore, an up-vote as well. Thanks.